# How to launch a powershell script from itself after rebooting the computer?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I was making a script to automatically install the LSPosed version of WSA that can be found [Here](https://github.com/insomnyawolf/MagiskOnWSALocalAutoInstaller) and since it may need to enable Hyper-V/WSL it ckecks if they are enabled and if they aren't, it enables them and then reboot.

You can run the script again to complete the building/instalation but it would be nice if you could "schedule it" to execute on the next boot as well.

Is it even possible (it needs to run as admin user)?

Comment: no problem, simply let the script create a scheduled task which runs at startup and executes the script

Comment: In Windows registry, you can add a registry value of type REG_SZ to key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run".  This will run for any user and run every time, so you will have to delete key when you no longer want your script to run.  You can change "Run" to "RunOnce", and it will delete itself.  But if your script needs to run again after a reboot, then you will have to add it again.  If you are currently logged on as the user who will log in next, then change "HKLM" to "HKCU".  For examples, just look in these keys and see what is already configured.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a PowerShell workflow. The can resume after a restart. So, you can install any prerequisites, restart the machine and resume - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_workflows?view=powershell-5.1#about-workflows